# Is there a way to build a Python module written in C with Windows OS?

Tags: python, c, windows, build

I found several solutions, but all of them imply working on other OSs, like `Linux`. Some say there is no way to build such module with `Windows` at all.

I work with C on `VSCode`, but I do not have a built-in compiler since I originally installed it for Python, and therefore I compile all C programs manually through `cmd` using `gcc` compiler.

So that is the question, how can I create a Python module in C language using Windows?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)?

Comment: @Jab I have, it basically describes how to do this with VSCode, but mine cannot implement that due to the absence of instruments on it

Comment: Have you tried installing the VSCode C compiler?

Comment: @lxop I hoped to find a way to do that with cmd commands or sth like that

Comment: You can still use the VSCode compiler from the command line. You asked how you can create a Python module in C using Windows - the docs linked by @Jab in the first comment show what to do. If you don't want to follow those docs, please explain why.

Comment: @lxop VSCode C extensions don't include the compiler, do you mean a workload like `Desktop Development with C++`?

Comment: @lxop I don't, because I recently had some silly problems when tried to get the compiler for VSCode, and I finally ended up installing mingw64 which is not the same thing as VSCode compiler

Comment: I have compiled Python modules written in C using the Microsoft tools before, so can't offer any further suggestions sorry. You might want to look into your "silly problems"

Comment: @lxop Well, I tried to get the compiler from the [MS source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp), but when I try to get `Microsoft C++ compiler on Windows` (is this the one you've been talking about?), it redirects me to the page which is about _using the Microsoft C++ toolset from the command line_. There it says that _If you've installed Visual Studio and a C++ workload, you have all the command-line tools._ The point is that _I do not!_

Comment: @lxop Since I originally installed VSCode for Python, I reckon I don't have a C++ workload, but I didn't find how to get it installed manually without reinstalling VSCode (which is what I do not want to do at all)

Comment: @lxop I did, but unsuccessfully, maybe they assume a user to have it by default. I think I should reinstall it anyway

Comment: VS and VS Code are different things. The workload mentioned above is only for VS, not VS Code. Tried VS, many times heavier, more complicated, works slower and looks much worse than VSCode. If there is no other way to solve my problem, I'll leave it unsolved for now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. Use the Python C API to embed python into your C project
2. Use something like SWIG or PyBindGen to create bindings to your C code, or a library like Boost.Python if you're creating a C++ project
3. Create a DLL from your C code and load it into your python project, calling the C functions directly
4. Use ctypes python library to build your C-type code directly in python project
5. Use something like Cython

You can look into this page for a brief summary of each of those methods as well as a list of pros/cons for each: https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/

Comment: I only want my C module to get imported into my Python code through the `import` statement

Comment: You can't really do that unless you rebuild your C module and wrap it with the Python C API or just export your functions to a DLL then load the DLL in your python module using ctypes.

Look into this: https://realpython.com/build-python-c-extension-module/

Comment: Got that, thanks. Now it seems there is another sort of the problem